# Today Extension: how to display long text?

Tags: ios8-today-widget

I don't know whether I'm doing something wrong or if it's not possible: I'd like to display a longer text, but the height seems to be limited to 568 pixels ([Maximum height of iOS 8 Today Extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24815957/maximum-height-of-ios-8-today-extension)). I'm using a `UITextView`, so I would expect it to scroll, but that's not possible either.

Isn't there any way to display the full text?

Answer (score 0):

Displaying such large text on a Notification Center widget, especially in iPhone 4S, 5 or 6, where space is limited, is a bad idea.

Instead, show a preview of the text, indicate that there is more text, and add a button to open the full app to read the rest of it.