# iOS Today Widget cut off at bottom

Tags: ios, swift, widget, cgsize

I have created a Widget extension for my app that appears in the 'Today View'. It works well however it cuts off the bottom of the content where the next widget starts. I have tried to adjust the height in `preferredContentSize` but it does not seem to change. Do you know where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This happens when the widget height is too large.

I don't remember it to be documented but you can find the max heights in this post:
[Maximum height of iOS 8 Today Extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24815957/maximum-height-of-ios-8-today-extension)

Answer (score 0):

It's not actually `preferredContentSize` fault, apple cut last widget off because of the bottom is use by apple for iPhoneX series, so you need to set part of your subview out of your super view like `50px`, that will work.